# Does victory point determine resource base opponents in Boom Beach?

Tags: boom-beach

Does current victory points of the player determine the opponent player one is matched against?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Boom Beach Wikia](http://boombeach.wikia.com/wiki/Matchmaking), the game does not care if the opponent has a high or low level at all. It only cares about the amount of Victory Points you have. The more Victory Points, the higher the level of the average opponent will be. This will also affect the resources bases you receive (occupied by opponents of course) as the owner of the base must have just enough Victory Points to become your opponent.

Yes, I've seen level 20's when I was a level 35. Do not underestimate the attacking power of weaker opponents, they can surprise you on how good they can be. Unclaimed resource bases' levels will go higher as you unlock more and more segments of the Archipelago, regardless of your current level or VP count.

> As your Victory Point count goes up, you will be matched up against harder Blackguard bases and player bases with similar Victory Point counts. Typically, higher Victory Point counts mean you will be matched up against higher level players. Your Victory Point count DOES affect what players own the Resource Base that you discover or refresh, but please note that Victory Points DO NOT affect the difficulty of Lt. Hammerman bases, Colonel Gearheart's War Factories, and Dr. Terror levels.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is based on your current victory points, read here on the [Boom Beach wikia](http://boombeach.wikia.com/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions)
 Sorry I can't be in more depth with this answer, it looks like you are looking for a simple Yes or No, if you want further information, edit it into your question and I'll go digging around and then edit my answer.

Comment: I have seen the page you mentioned but i don't quite agree to it. I have user bases of level 35 on my map though the resource bases i have on my map are as high as level 50.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is !

The level doesn't change anything, only Victory Points. I'm level 46, with 580 VP, and my opponents are level 50-55 etc...
It depends of your place in the leaderboard ;)